# ZFS-enhanced way to copy files over network?

Tags: macos, freebsd, cp, zfs

What is the best way to copy files from one computer to another using ZFS or checksumming?

I have a FreeNAS server with ZFS and a Mac with Mojave and ZFS.

I want to copy a large (4 TB) Time Machine sparsebundle from the server to the ZVOL on the Mac over the network.

I wonder if there is a ZFS-enhanced way to do this, which perhaps includes metadata or checksums.

Apparently ZFS only includes options for copying (send/receive) complete filesystems or volumes, not individual files.

I found the command

`cp -z`

on an Oracle online manual, but this apparently does not work in the macOS terminal.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you use Rsync?

Comment: Questions about the FreeBSD operating system and its utilities are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to leverage ZFS for this using any of it's features other than send/receive. Unless you are transferring an whole fs or volume snapshot (full or incremental), ZFS can't help you.